# Administrator cannot encrypt/decrypt in AWS KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-kms, aws-policies

I am using the *Key Management service (KMS)* in AWS and am currently setting up [key policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html).

I created two roles *KmsUser* and *KmsAdmin* and attached the following key policy to my CMK:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "KMS KeyAdmin access",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {"AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/KmsAdmin",
      "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/myadmin"
      ]},
      "Action": [
        "kms:Create*",
        "kms:Describe*",
        "kms:Enable*",
        "kms:List*",
        "kms:Put*",
        "kms:Update*",
        "kms:Revoke*",
        "kms:Disable*",
        "kms:Get*",
        "kms:Delete*",
        "kms:TagResource",
        "kms:UntagResource",
        "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
        "kms:CancelKeyDeletion"
      ],
    "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "KMS KeyUser access",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {"AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/KmsUser"
      ]},
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is that now if I try to use my key as the *myadmin* user (which has the *AdministratorAccess* policy attached) I get an error in the CLI:

```sh
$ aws kms encrypt --key-id "alias/test-key" --plaintext fileb:///tmp/plaintext.dat

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the Encrypt operation: User: arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/myadmin is not authorized to perform: kms:Encrypt on resource: arn:aws:kms:eu-north-1:1234567890:key/99999999-9999-9999-9999-99999999999
```

What is especially strange, is that the [IAM policy simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp) tells me that everything should work as expected:

[image]

If I manually add the *myadmin* user as a pricipal to the *Key User* policy, everything works fine.

Comment: Actually above policy is for duty segregation. A key administrator is not supposed to be able to encrypt or decrypt data with the key. So admin can manage keys, but cannot access data. Key user can encrypt or decrypt data, but cannot manage keys. So the correct answer was to use KmsUser role to decrypt/encrypt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a statement like this to your key policy:

```
        {
            "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:root"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
```

This allows the account to have access to the key, which is required to enable IAM access to it.

Comment: That worked, thank you. Do you know why KMS requires explicit admin permissions in contrast to the other AWS services?

Comment: So is this a bug in the policy simulator then? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's not a bug, the simulator is just looking at the data you gave it. It doesn't know what the key policies are. It doesn't even know/care if the resources are real. [Using key policies in KMS](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-kms-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/key-policies.md#using-key-policies-in-aws-kms) gives a pretty good rundown of how the key policies work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating the KMS construct using `AWS CDK` then make sure to set the  `trustAccountIdentities` to `true`. Example in TypeScript

```
const passwordEncryptionKey = new kms.Key(this, 'MyKey', {
  enabled: true,
  trustAccountIdentities: true,
});
```

Docs are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-kms-readme.html#key-policies)